# Does "I have had this cough for a month" mean I still have the cough?

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect

What about, "I got **a cough** about one month back." Should this be qualified with "**and I still have it**" to mean that I have still got the cough? Is it right to call the cough, "**a cough**"?

In the sentence "I've had this cough for sometime **now**", what does the word '**now**' do? Would the sentence say the same thing if the word '**now**' was absent?

Comment: The sentence would mean the same with or without **now**. In your example, **now** is used as an intensifier, like an exclamation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've had this cough for a month.

This implies that you still have the cough.

> I had a cough for a month.

This implies that the cough is over.

Your usage of `cough` is fine as the verb refers the the action and the noun can refer "an illness characterized by frequent coughing."

Answer (score 0):

Just like Leo said, this is a sentence which its English tense is Present Perfect.
Present Perfect is an action or situation related to the past, it started in the past and continuous in the present. For example:

I have been playing The Witcher 3 since yesterday and I have not slept anything. (Means that I have been playing and I might want to keep playing it and I haven't slept until that moment, and maybe I will not sleep until I finish playing the game.

You have asked a question in English Language Learners and they have answered you 2 times.
(Means that they have asnwered you two times but they can keep answering you.

Comment: "sleep anything" is not used as "sleep" is an intransitive verb and doesn't take a direct object.